# How to compare the ICCID of the simcard that i've stored to the new simcard inserted

Tags: android

I'm creating an android application that can determine the ICCID of
a sim card (getting details in sim card information),then stored it in
a database. After storing all the information of sim card, I want to
compare it to the new sim card that I've inserted in my phone, and tells
that new sim card is detected. This is my code. It is only for viewing all my info of my sim card.

public class View_SimId extends Main {

```
String simCountry, simOperatorCode, simOperatorName, simSerial;
EditText viewSimSerial, viewSimCountry, viewSimOpCode, viewSimOpName;
Button btnSimIdBack;
Cursor c3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_sim_id);

    viewSimSerial = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.viewSimSerial);
    viewSimCountry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.viewSimCountry);
    viewSimOpCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.viewSimOpCode);
    viewSimOpName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.viewSimOpName);
    btnSimIdBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSimIdBack);
    btnSimIdBack.setOnClickListener(this);

    TelephonyManager  telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    int simState = telephonyManager.getSimState();

    switch (simState) {
        case (TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT): break;
        case (TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED): break;
        case (TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED): break;
        case (TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED): break;
        case (TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN): break;
        case (TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY): {

            // Get the SIM country ISO code
            simCountry = telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
            // Get the operator code of the active SIM (MCC + MNC)
            simOperatorCode = telephonyManager.getSimOperator();
            // Get the name of the SIM operator
            simOperatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
            // Get the SIM’s serial number
            simSerial = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
         }
     }

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO sim_info VALUES('" 
            + simCountry + "','" + simOperatorCode + "','" 
            + simOperatorName + "','" + simSerial + "');");

    c3 = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM sim_info", null);
    c3.moveToFirst();

    viewSimSerial.setText(c3.getString(0));
    viewSimCountry.setText(c3.getString(1));
    viewSimOpCode.setText(c3.getString(2));
    viewSimOpName.setText(c3.getString(3));

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view==btnSimIdBack){
        startActivity(new Intent(View_SimId.this, Main.class));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: how can i compare the i've stored ICCID to the new putted simcard? @MikeM.

Comment: What specific problem are you having? You just need to check if the returned values of `getSimSerialNumber()` are different.