# How to programmatically compare the 2 different ICCID

Tags: android, iccid

I'm currently creating an app that can automatically compare the 2 different ICCID also can send it automatically into sms. Can someone help me on how to compare these 2 ICCID, which is programmatically.

Comment: What problem were you having with the code you posted in [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890825/how-to-compare-the-iccid-of-the-simcard-that-ive-stored-to-the-new-simcard-inse#comment57520209_34890825)?

Comment: i'm having a difficulty in comparing these two ICCID in an automatic way, (auto compare) even if there is no trigger @MikeM.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to do, because it sounds like the comparison isn't the actual problem. Do you want to do this in an Activity when the user opens your app? Do you want some sort of pop-up at boot to send the SMS if the SIM is different? Do you want to schedule a check at a certain time? What, exactly?

Comment: what im trying to do is  to get first the ICCID of my simcard stored in my android phone, then locate it in the database. So whenever, i putted another simcard in my android phone, my app will automatically run and compare the ICCID that i've stored earlier in my database to be compared to the newly putted simcard, then make a notification that simcard is change. @MikeM.

Comment: Well, apparently most, if not all, devices fire the `android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast when that happens. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528464/how-to-monitor-sim-state-change). For those that might not, you'll have to use some other trigger; e.g., the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009295/how-to-detect-the-sim-card-change-in-android-phone#comment14388531_11009295) has links to several questions about this topic. Please try some of those suggestions first. As it is, your question is a little too broad.

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. for your effort. This link may help me a lot in my thesis project.